# Reduce varchar2(n char) size to varchar2(n) when value length = n but lentgthb = x*n

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_val (
  name VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL
);
```

Let's say I insert with the following:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_VAL (name) VALUES('££££££££££'); --data here may be variable characters string so size may vary from 10 to 40 bytes
```

Now the value in the table is 10 characters but 20 bytes.

And say I want to reduce the size of the column to 10 bytes, I don't care about the data loss.
I do the following:

```
UPDATE test_val SET name = substr(name,1,10) WHERE lengthb(name)>10;

ALTER TABLE test_val
MODIFY name varchar2(10);
```

And I get an error that the value in the column is too big, because substr(name,1,10) leaves 10 symbols.

So my question is: Is there a **substr** alternative for substringing values to number of bytes, if not, is there another way to reduce column value so I could run alter table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`substrb` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) that calculates in bytes (as well as `substrc`, `substr2`, and `substr4` to get a number of Unicode characters, UCS2, and UCS4 code points).  If your database character set is `AL32UTF8`, remember that characters may require between 1 and 4 bytes of storage-- I don't know off the top of my head what happens if you try to get 10 bytes of data from a string when that would cut off a character in the middle.

Comment: Worked fine. When used on string with 10 chars and 40 bytes it returned 10 bytes which was 2 complete symbols and some new symbol, which is totally fine in my situation

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [`substrb`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm) -

```
UPDATE test_val SET name = substrb(name,1,10) WHERE lengthb(name)>10;
```